# Jquery script stopped working correctly in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

The problem is as follows:
Scripts suddenly stopped working in Google Chrome. However in IE everything works as it should.
Look at the website: agenceinteractive.com
When you're scrolling down, it's all smooth and nice, but as you move up, the page is not visible twitch and smooth transition. It's the same for when you're moving from right to left.

Just 2-3 weeks ago, everything worked as it should.
What is the reason, I can't understand, Chrome has not been updated.

Comment: try reinstalling...;)

Comment: You need to post the code that's having the problem. Posting a link to a production web site is useless -- when you fix the problem, how will future readers of the question be able to see what the problem is?

Comment: works good in `chrome 34.0.1847.116`

Comment: I'm sorry. Chrome has been updated

Answer (score 0):

```
// animation top & bottom
  iNewTop = (indexThemeCurrent) * $(window).height();
  iSwipeTop = -iNewTop;
  var iOldTop = oContainer.css('top');
  if (-iNewTop != iOldTop.substr(0, iOldTop.length - 2)) 
  {
    //console.log('déplacement top bottom');
    if(bCss){
        oAbsoluteTheme.css('left', '0px');
        oContainer.css('top','-' + iNewTop + 'px');
    }else{
        //console.log(iSpeedAnimate * Math.abs(indexThemeCurrent - indexThemePrevious));
        // Hide btn nav
    hideNav('all');
    //alert('down');
        oContainer.animate({
            top: '-' + iNewTop + 'px'
          }, 500, 
          function() {
              alert('complete');
          oAbsoluteTheme.css('left', '0px');
          indexSectionPrevious = 0;
          });
    }
 }
```

the problem is that when we move down, then everything is OK. But when up no animation. Jumps to slide without animation.

As I said before, the problem appeared suddenly (now I know that after updating chrome). Everything worked correctly in Chrome 37